# Random Seed in PIC18F

Tags: random, pic, random-seed

I'm going to run modified DES code(C language) on the PIC18F2550 microcontroller.
For this I am using mplabx IDE v 2 and Mplab xc8 v 1.30.

To modify the code, I need a random number so that each run will produce different numbers.

I want to use the rand function but I need a good seed for Srand function!

Good seed can be time, but since there is no such thing as a micro or I do not know!!

Answer (score 2):

You can store an integer value in EEPROM. When the device boots, you use it as a seed and then increment and store it again so that at every reboot you will have a different seed, producing a different sequence for each run. That should be enough for what you want.

If you need something a little more sofisticated, you can try this [555+ADC random seed circuit](http://hackaday.com/2012/10/01/using-a-555-timer-and-adc-as-a-random-seed/).